# Red Book fur example not rendering fur (Linux/nvidia gtx675mx)

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, nvidia

I trying to get the Red Book (8th edition) chapter 10 Fur example to work on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop with Nvidia GTX675MX

I've changed the code to use SDL2 and glm but everything else is as it is in the Red Book.

The code compiles and runs but the 3d object is not fur shaded.

Can anyone spot any errors or is my GPU simply not up to the task?

(Full source is here: http://openme.gl/redbook_chapter_10_fur.zip)

```cpp
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS    
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp> 
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "vermilion.h"
#include "vutils.h"
#include "vbm.h"

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(x)  ((const void*) (x))

#define PROGRAM_NAME "Red Book - Chapter 10 - Fur"

void Initialize();
void Display();
void Finalize(void);
void Reshape(int width, int height);

float aspect;
GLuint base_prog;
GLuint fur_prog;
GLuint fur_texture;
VBObject object;

GLint fur_model_matrix_pos;
GLint fur_projection_matrix_pos;
GLint base_model_matrix_pos;
GLint base_projection_matrix_pos;


void Initialize()
{

  base_prog = glCreateProgram();

  static const char base_vs_source[] =
    "#version 410\n"
    "\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec4 position_in;\n"
    "layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal_in;\n"
    "layout (location = 2) in vec2 texcoord_in;\n"
    "\n"
    "uniform mat4 model_matrix;\n"
    "uniform mat4 projection_matrix;\n"
    "\n"
    "out VS_FS_VERTEX\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vec3 normal;\n"
    "} vertex_out;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vertex_out.normal = normal_in;\n"
    "    gl_Position = projection_matrix * (model_matrix * position_in);\n"
    "}\n";

  static const char base_fs_source[] =
    "#version 410\n"
    "\n"
    "layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
    "\n"
    "in VS_FS_VERTEX\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vec3 normal;\n"
    "} vertex_in;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vec3 normal = vertex_in.normal;\n"
    "    color = vec4(0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 1.0) * (0.2 + pow(abs(normal.z), 4.0)) + vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.0) * pow(abs(normal.z), 137.0);\n"
    "}\n";

  vglAttachShaderSource(base_prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, base_vs_source);
  vglAttachShaderSource(base_prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, base_fs_source);

  glLinkProgram(base_prog);
  glUseProgram(base_prog);

  base_model_matrix_pos = glGetUniformLocation(base_prog, "model_matrix");
  base_projection_matrix_pos = glGetUniformLocation(base_prog, "projection_matrix");

  fur_prog = glCreateProgram();

  static const char fur_vs_source[] =
    "#version 410\n"
    "\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec4 position_in;\n"
    "layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal_in;\n"
    "layout (location = 2) in vec2 texcoord_in;\n"
    "\n"
    "out VS_GS_VERTEX\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vec3 normal;\n"
    "    vec2 tex_coord;\n"
    "} vertex_out;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vertex_out.normal = normal_in;\n"
    "    vertex_out.tex_coord = texcoord_in;\n"
    "    gl_Position = position_in;\n"
    "}\n";

  static const char fur_gs_source[] =
    "#version 410\n"
    "\n"
    "layout (triangles) in;\n"
    "layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 240) out;\n"
    "\n"
    "uniform mat4 model_matrix;\n"
    "uniform mat4 projection_matrix;\n"
    "\n"
    "uniform int fur_layers = 30;\n"
    "uniform float fur_depth = 5.0;\n"
    "\n"
    "in VS_GS_VERTEX\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vec3 normal;\n"
    "    vec2 tex_coord;\n"
    "} vertex_in[];\n"
    "\n"
    "out GS_FS_VERTEX\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vec3 normal;\n"
    "    vec2 tex_coord;\n"
    "    flat float fur_strength;\n"
    "} vertex_out;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    int i, layer;\n"
    "    float disp_delta = 1.0 / float(fur_layers);\n"
    "    float d = 0.0;\n"
    "    vec4 position;\n"
    "\n"
    "    for (layer = 0; layer < fur_layers; layer++)\n"
    "    {\n"
    "        for (i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++) {\n"
    "            vec3 n = vertex_in[i].normal;\n"
    "            vertex_out.normal = n;\n"
    "            vertex_out.tex_coord = vertex_in[i].tex_coord;\n"
    "            vertex_out.fur_strength = 1.0 - d;\n"
    "            position = gl_in[i].gl_Position + vec4(n * d * fur_depth, 0.0);\n"
    "            gl_Position = projection_matrix * (model_matrix * position);\n"
    "            EmitVertex();\n"
    "        }\n"
    "        d += disp_delta;\n"
    "        EndPrimitive();\n"
    "    }\n"
    "}\n";

  static const char fur_fs_source[] =
    "#version 410\n"
    "\n"
    "layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
    "\n"
    "uniform sampler2D fur_texture;\n"
    "uniform vec4 fur_color = vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0);\n"
    "\n"
    "in GS_FS_VERTEX\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vec3 normal;\n"
    "    vec2 tex_coord;\n"
    "    flat float fur_strength;\n"
    "} fragment_in;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    vec4 rgba = texture(fur_texture, fragment_in.tex_coord);\n"
    "    float t = rgba.a;\n"
    "    t *= fragment_in.fur_strength;\n"
    "    color = fur_color * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, t);\n"
    "}\n";

  vglAttachShaderSource(fur_prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, fur_vs_source);
  vglAttachShaderSource(fur_prog, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, fur_gs_source);
  vglAttachShaderSource(fur_prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fur_fs_source);

  glLinkProgram(fur_prog);
  glUseProgram(fur_prog);

  fur_model_matrix_pos = glGetUniformLocation(fur_prog, "model_matrix");
  fur_projection_matrix_pos = glGetUniformLocation(fur_prog, "projection_matrix");

  glGenTextures(1, &fur_texture);
  unsigned char * tex = (unsigned char *)malloc(1024 * 1024 * 4);
  memset(tex, 0, 1024 * 1024 * 4);

  int n, m;

  for (n = 0; n < 256; n++)
    {
      for (m = 0; m < 1270; m++)
        {
      int x = rand() & 0x3FF;
      int y = rand() & 0x3FF;
      tex[(y * 1024 + x) * 4 + 0] = (rand() & 0x3F) + 0xC0;
      tex[(y * 1024 + x) * 4 + 1] = (rand() & 0x3F) + 0xC0;
      tex[(y * 1024 + x) * 4 + 2] = (rand() & 0x3F) + 0xC0;
      tex[(y * 1024 + x) * 4 + 3] = n;
        }
    }

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fur_texture);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  free(tex);

  object.LoadFromVBM("ninja.vbm", 0, 1, 2);
}

void Display()
{
  float t = float(SDL_GetTicks() & 0x3FFF) / float(0x3FFF);
  static const glm::vec3 X(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  static const glm::vec3 Y(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  static const glm::vec3 Z(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  glClearDepth(1.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glm::mat4 p(glm::frustum(-1.0f, 1.0f, aspect, -aspect, 1.0f, 5000.0f));
  glm::mat4 m;

  m = glm::mat4(glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0),glm::vec3(0.0f,
                            0.0f,
                            /* 100.0f * sinf(6.28318531f * t)*/ - 130.0f)) *
        //glm::rotation(360.0f * t, X) *
        glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0),36.0f * t * 1.0f, Y) *
        glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0),18.0f, Z) *
        glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0),glm::vec3(0.0f, -80.0f, 0.0f)));

  glUseProgram(base_prog);

  glUniformMatrix4fv(base_model_matrix_pos, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(m));
  glUniformMatrix4fv(base_projection_matrix_pos, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(p));

  glDisable(GL_BLEND);
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

  object.Render();

  glUseProgram(fur_prog);

  glUniformMatrix4fv(fur_model_matrix_pos, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(m));
  glUniformMatrix4fv(fur_projection_matrix_pos, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(p));

  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
  object.Render();
  glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
  glDisable(GL_BLEND);

}

void Finalize(void)
{
  glUseProgram(0);
  glDeleteProgram(fur_prog);
}

void Reshape(int width, int height)
{
  glViewport(0, 0 , width, height);

  aspect = float(height) / float(width);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  SDL_Window *mainwindow; /* Our window handle */
  SDL_GLContext maincontext; /* Our opengl context handle */

  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) { /* Initialize SDL's Video subsystem */
    std::cout << "Unable to initialize SDL"; 
    return 1;
  }

  /* Request opengl 4.4 context. */
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);

  /* Turn on double buffering with a 24bit Z buffer.
   * You may need to change this to 16 or 32 for your system */
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

  /* Create our window centered at 512x512 resolution */
  mainwindow = SDL_CreateWindow(PROGRAM_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                512, 512, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
  if (!mainwindow){ /* Die if creation failed */
    std::cout << "SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    SDL_Quit();
    return 1;
  } 

  /* Create our opengl context and attach it to our window */
  maincontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mainwindow);

  GLenum rev;
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 
  rev = glewInit();

  if (GLEW_OK != rev){
    std::cout << "Error: " << glewGetErrorString(rev) << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  } else {
    std::cout << "GLEW Init: Success!" << std::endl;
  }

  /* This makes our buffer swap syncronized with the monitor's vertical refresh */

  SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1); 

  bool quit=false;

  Initialize();
  Reshape(512,512);

  SDL_Event event;

  while(!quit){

    Display();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainwindow);

    while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ){
      if( event.type == SDL_QUIT ){
    quit = true;
      }
      if(event.type ==SDL_WINDOWEVENT){
    if(event.window.event = SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED){
      int w,h;
      SDL_GetWindowSize(mainwindow,&w,&h);
      Reshape(w,h);
    }
      }
    }
  } 

  Finalize();

  /* Delete our opengl context, destroy our window, and shutdown SDL */
  SDL_GL_DeleteContext(maincontext);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(mainwindow);
  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is way to much code! Either you have to narrow it down by debugging yourself, or if you want a more general code-review [there's a site for that](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (though they may not help you with specifics).

Comment: I have posted the source to code review, but I don't think you can write a fur shader in much less code.

Comment: There is no error checking for the shader compilation and linking output. Usually when a shader does not compile the pipeline displays everything normally without the shaders.

Comment: I added: glGetProgramiv(fur_prog,GL_LINK_STATUS,&params); after the link command and it returns false, so guess there's an error in the fur shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added

```
glGetProgramInfoLog(fur_prog, sizeof(buffer), &length, buffer);
std::cout << length << std::endl;  
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```

And got

```
Geometry info
-------------
(0) : error C6033: Hardware limitation reached, can only emit 146 vertices of this size
```

Changed max_vertices to 146 and now the shader compiles and links.